# How are these radio streaming app's functionality implemented?

Tags: android

I've came across some radio app's that share a common, how can I say, way to implement their functionality, and (since I'm new on android dev) I'm really curious about it.

I'll use some images from the app "Simple Radio" to illustrate my doubt.
So, in what I call the main activity, you simply have a feed of radios from where you can choose one to play.

[image]

If no radio is playing/stopped on background, what you see when a radio is choosen is this activity, the one I call the streaming activity:

[image]

However, if one radio was playing/stopped on background, and you choose another one, what you'll see is this toolbar in the end of the feed:

[image]

So.. I know there's a background service for streaming the choosen radio, but how do they manage to control the radio both on the main and streaming activity? Is that possible because services (and it's current state) can be accessed from anywhere or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know there's a background service for streaming the choosen radio, but how do they manage to control the radio both on the main and streaming activity? Is that possible because services (and it's current state) can be accessed from anywhere or something?

The background service is actually a background Service, an Android controller that is independent of activities.

This controller runs until it is told to stop, and has nothing to do what is visually on screen. The visual components can communicate with the Service to send instructions to it and vice versa.